# Being treated vs to be treated

Tags: infinitive-vs-gerund

An outpatient is a patient _____ at a hospital during the thay but not staying overnight

Which one is correct,  being treated or to be treated?
I think it's being,  though. But I don't know why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> An outpatient is a patient ***being*** treated at a hospital during the day [not *thay] but not staying overnight.

This is a definition of an outpatient and is not concerned with the future, but with the treatment of such patients in general. Here, *being* is a present participle used as a an adjective, meaning "which are".

The infinitive *to be treated* means "which are to be treated/ will be treated", and this particular reference to the future is not accurate. Plus, the symmetry of the contrast must be preserved: ***being treated*** is balanced by ***staying***, whereas *to be treated* would disrupt this balance and make the sentence sound awkward.